# How do you check the state of an application if you know the application handle?

Tags: vb.net, handle

I am writing a routine vb.net that launches another third party application through its APIs. The application is running in the background(the window is hidden). However, from its API, I am able to get the application handle returned as an integer.

Is there a way to get the application state, such as running, closed, or crashed from the application handle in vb.net? For example, I want to return some messages, like the application is launched, the application is running, etc.

Also, I want to know. If an application is closed, is there a possibility that the integer(application handle) representing the application will be assigned to something else?

Comment: Try the [Process.GetProcessById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76fkb36k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then use the returned Process instance to monitor it.

Comment: Assuming the "application handle" is a `ProcessId` (add the column to task manager to check) then you can fetch a process object (`Process.GetProcessById()`) if that fails then its been closed or crashed, if it succeeds (and its name is what you expect) its running (or hung) and you can hook into the `Exited` event. The closest to "is hung" is to p/invoke `IsHungAppWindow()` but this is not very accurate in its diagnosis and requires a window handle.

Comment: No 2 running processes have the same ProcessID however once a process exits another can begin with the same ID.